Bunch of valid events in search console. No impressions
I've been trying to do some Schema setup for them to show up in Google. And right now, I've got it into the search console, no errors or even warnings.
So I've got 400+ events registered for 2 weeks, but still, 0 impressions. The things never showed up in a search, it seems.
What could I be doing wrong? My website does get at least 100 searches for it in particular per day, and the location where the events are are at 900+ searches per day.
So why would my graph still be at 0 impressions even if Google tells me everything is good?
They are Events (tried SportsEvent before, didn't work either) and are put into the page as an ld+json in the body.


Are they events you organise, or are you a listings site?  When I search for events near me, it only seems to show things that are connected to well known ticket companies.  I'm not that familiar with events schema, but I know with things like reviews schema, Google only show reviews from Google approved review sites for everything but very specific site searches.

We organise and/or host them. And currently at the location, I google events near me and they dont popup. Hell, I cant seem to pop any events.
